# Can't retrieve data with dot symbol from sql database

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, special-characters

In my project (vb.net) I store the ip address of a website in a table with column of type `nvarchar`. But I can't retrieve it from the table. I wonder if its a problem with "dot" symbol. Please help.

This is the command that I use

```
 query = "select *from restricted_sites where site_address='" + webip + "'"
```

`webip` is the ip address of web site.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Net
Public Class restrict
    Private Sub clear_button_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles clear_button.Click
        site_TextBox1.Text = ""
        addr_TextBox1.Text = ""
    End Sub
    Private Sub submit_button_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles submit_button.Click
        Dim connectionstr As String
        Dim query As String
        Dim conn As SqlConnection
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand
        Dim webip As String
        Dim hostname As IPHostEntry = Dns.GetHostByName(addr_TextBox1.Text)
        Dim ip As IPAddress() = hostname.AddressList
        Try
            webip = ip(0).ToString
            connectionstr = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\URLTrack.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True"
            conn = New SqlConnection(connectionstr)
            conn.Open()
            query = "insert into restricted_sites values('" + site_TextBox1.Text + "','" + webip + "')"
            cmd = New SqlCommand(query, conn)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("Website added for restriction", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
            conn.Close()
        Catch ex As SqlException
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

```
Private Sub Combox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Combox1.KeyPress
        If e.KeyChar = Convert.ToChar(Keys.Enter) Then
            Dim connectionstr As String
            Dim query As String
            Dim cmd As SqlCommand
            Dim reader As SqlDataReader
            Dim conn As SqlConnection
            Dim url As String = ""
            Dim webip As String
            Dim hostname As IPHostEntry = Dns.GetHostByName(Combox1.Text)
            Dim ip As IPAddress() = hostname.AddressList
            webip = ip(0).ToString
            connectionstr = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\URLTrack.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True"
            conn = New SqlConnection(connectionstr)
            conn.Open()
            query = "select * from restricted_sites where site_address='" + webip + "'"
            cmd = New SqlCommand(query, conn)
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            While (reader.Read())
                url = reader(2)
            End While
            reader.Close()
            MsgBox(url, MsgBoxStyle.Information)
            If webip <> url Then
                AxWebBrowser1.Navigate(Combox1.Text)
                Combox1.Text = AxWebBrowser1.LocationURL
            Else
                MsgBox("This Web Page is Restricted.Contact the ADMIN for Further Info", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
            End If
        End If
        If e.KeyChar = Convert.ToChar(Keys.Escape) Then
            AxWebBrowser1.Stop()
        End If
    End Sub
```

The second code is the comparing part.
query = "select * from restricted_sites where site_address='" + webip + "'"
this code is the problem.
This is my code for restricting web sites through matching with ip address stored in database,when the url is being navigated.

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Can you please help me with how i can get rid SQL Injection Vulnerability?

Comment: could you check `webip` if it has a value?

Comment: webip is getting a value.It gets the ip address.I've checked it.Problem is here, url = reader(2).This url doesn't come up with a value.

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error on your query. you forgot the space between `*` and `from`.

```
select *from restricted_sites
       ^ here
```

it should be

```
select * from restricted_sites
```

side note, since you are using VBNet, please do parameterized your query by using `adonet` *command and parameters* as your current query is susceptible with `SQL Injection`.

Comment: Thank you John Woo for your quick reply.I've tried that,but it still doesn't retrieve the ip.Also thanx for your advice.Could you tell me how i can parameterize query using ado.net?

Comment: can you include sample records list on your table?

Comment: I have two fields site_name and site_address..site_name - facebook site_address 66.220.152.16

Comment: it may be problem on your vbnet code, can you include it on your question? and so we can fix it from `sql injection`

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a space between the `*` and the `from` like so:

```
query = "select * from restricted_sites where site_address='" + webip + "'"
```

Dot symbols (presumably you meant in the webip) won't be a problem because it is in a String

Comment: Thank you Suhail Patel for your answer.I'm afraid that didn't work so well.

Answer (score 0):

If all you are doing is checking if an IP address string is in the database, you only need to count the number of occurences of that string:

```
query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM restricted_sites WHERE site_address = @WebIp;"
cmd = New SqlCommand(query, conn)
' assumes the ip address column is 15 chars '
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@WebIp", _
                                          .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, _
                                          .Size = 15, _
                                          .Value = webip})

conn.Open()
Dim nFound = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
conn.Close()

If nFound = 0 Then
    ' site is not in restricted list
End If
```

Also, you should not use `SELECT *` in code other than for testing - use the column names instead of * and only retrieve what you need.

Comment: Thanx for your reply.I'm matching the ip address of a domain name entered by a user on the browser and checking whether it is present in the restricted_sites table where the blocked sites are stored by the admin.

Comment: This code doesn't meet my requirements.Thank you for your advice on select statement.